# How to run multiple functions in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I need to use the turtle function to create a shape that moves and that can be paused.  I figured out how to do that but now I need to make it run for 10 seconds then end.  It also needs to print the seconds as the countdown runs and the timer needs to pause when the app is paused.

This is what I have so far.

```
import turtle
import time


wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor('blue')

player = turtle.Turtle()
player.color('yellow')
player.shape('triangle')
player.penup()
speed=1


def PlayerPause():
    global speed
    speed = 0
def PlayerPlay():
    global speed
    speed = 1
    while True:
        player.forward(speed)
        player.left(speed)

def Timer():
    seconds = 11
    for i in range(1,11):
        print(str(seconds - i)+ ' Seconds remain')
        time.sleep(1)
    print('GAME OVER')


turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(PlayerPause, 'p')
turtle.onkey(PlayerPlay, 'r')
turtle.onkey(Timer, 'e')

wn.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you practice "incremental development."  That means instead writing a whole bunch of code and then trying to make it work, you make just one relatively small thing work, then gradually add more functions, one small step at a time.

I'll sketch how you could do this for this question.

1. Get something to happen once a second.  Just make some kind of visible change once a second.  It could be making some object alternately appear and disappear.  It can be anything that is easy, visible, and doesn't break what you already have.  The Screen class has an `ontimer` method you can use for this.
2. Only after the first step is working, start counting seconds and displaying the counter.  Don't worry about pausing or terminating.  Just make a counter that shows increasing numbers as long as the script runs.
3. Change it to shut everything down when the counter gets to ten.
4. Change it to count down from ten to zero instead of up from zero to ten.
5. Change the timer function to check whether the action is paused.  If so, it should not change the seconds counter.

If you get stuck on any step, you can post a more specific question.